# functions with positive Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Information about the class of compactly supported smooth functions $u$ on $Ω\subset R^n$ such that $Δu≥0?$ Do a significant class of such function exist?

NB. This type of function may be useful in the problems of controllability.

In the case $n=1$, we can construct geometrically some functions with the above mentioned conditions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function

Answer (score 1):

Look up superharmonic and subharmonic functions.